# scala: how to wrap execution of subclass constructor?

Tags: scala

in scala, i have a base class and a number of child classes. without adding code to a child class or changing the instantiation of a child class, i would like the base class to be able to call some code both before and after the child constructor is executed. before is easy since the base class constructor is called before the child's, but i don't see a way to handle the after case. as a bit of example code:

```
class A {
  // do some stuff before child constructor is called
  // ...

  // do some other stuff after child constructor is called
  // this could be a method or inline in the constructor, doesn't matter.
}    

class B extends A { // stuff happens in between }

class C extends A { // stuff happens in between }
etc 

val b = new B // everything happens inside, no other method call needed
```

is this behavior possible? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Scala 2.9, you can arrange something like this:

```
class A { 
  println("Hi")
}
class B extends A with DelayedInit {
  private[this] var count = 0
  println("Hey")
  def delayedInit(x: => Unit) {
    x
    count += 1
    if (count==2) { println("There") }
  }
}
class C extends B { println("Ho") }
class D extends C { println("Ha") }
```

This takes advantage of the new `DelayedInit` trait which sends delayed constructors from the current and all child classes to a `delayedInit` method.  Unfortunately, since there is not a termination signal, you're limited to skipping a single constructor.  So for `C`, we get:

```
scala> new C
Hi
Hey
Ho
There
```

where the "There" block has magically appeared *after* the "Ho" block from `C`.  Unfortunately if you extend `C`, the new initialization happens last:

```
scala> new D
Hi
Hey
Ho
There
Ha
```

(You don't really need `A` there...I just put it there to illustrate what happens with superclasses.)

Comment: Was this the intended usage of `DelayedInit`? It's scary!

Comment: @huynhjl - Not really, as far as I can tell.  If it was the intended usage, I would have expected the single method to be split into two (one to register the constructor and one to execute when all were registered) or to have some other mechanism to determine the end of the list.  I think it was intended for use in classes that always use a common method--like `main` or `run` or `act`--so that you could put the code to execute in as if it were the constructor.  You then still _call_ `main` or `act` or whatever, which the superclass defines to run through all child constructors.

Comment: @rex this is really interesting, i'm trying to figure out how to make this work in a way that always wraps the last one no matter how many subclasses there are. that seems potentially impossible in the way that you pointed out though.

Comment: @rex the upside is it appears that there's nothing stopping this from wrapping all invocations past a certain depth though.

Comment: @Heinrich Schmetterling - If you know the depth so you can trigger on the last one, you can wrap (or reorder!) as many as you like.  If you don't know the depth, I don't think there's anything you can do unless you're willing to call a method in addition to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

An 'end of concrete class' callback is possible, 
the code below outputs :

```
hello
world1
world2
world3
end of the worlds !

trait A extends DelayedInit {

  def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
    body
    println("end of the worlds !")
  }
}

trait B extends A { println("hello") }
trait C extends B { println("world1") }
trait D extends C { println("world2") }

object Zozo extends  D {
  println("world3")
}
```